# Why I am getting POST 404 when Calendly is posting data to my endpoint

Tags: calendly

I created Calendly Webhook Subscription by following their [instructions](https://developer.calendly.com/api-docs/b3A6NTkxNDI1-create-webhook-subscription). My backend is written in NodeJS + Express. I am trying to implement Calendly webhook while I got the trial period. I am exposing the endpoint `/webhooks/calendly/calendlyWebhook` on localhost:8080 and I am doing it through ngrok, because Calendly supports only https protocol. I see in my logs Calendly sending a post request to the endpoint, but I am seeing it being 404: `POST /webhooks/calendly/calendlyWebhook 404`.

Here is my webhook file called calendlyWebhook.js

```
const { Router } = require('express');

const calendlyWebhookRouter = Router();

calendlyWebhookRouter.post('/calendlyWebhook', async (req, res) => {
  console.log("Hello from calendly webhook ✅")
  return res.statusCode(200).send('Ok')
})

module.exports = {
  calendlyWebhookRouter,
};
```

And here is my index.js file where I initialize the router

```
...
...

const {calendlyWebhookRouter} = require('./webhooks/calendlyWebhook');
app.use('/webhooks/calendly/calendlyWebhook', calendlyWebhookRouter);

...
```

What exactly I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The webhook route contains `calendlyWebhook` twice (once in the app.use path and once in the calendlyWebhookRouter path). As a result, `calendlyWebhookRouter` will only be called when a POST request is sent to `/webhooks/calendly/calendlyWebhook/calendlyWebhook`.

Removing `calendlyWebhook` from the app.use route path should resolve the issue:

```js
app.use('/webhooks/calendly', calendlyWebhookRouter);
```